# Map JSON to case class for scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am trying to write test cases using scala test for the components.
My application takes JSON through the REST endpoints map it to the `case class` via `Akka http entity mapping`, Now while writing the test case all I want to do is Map my json to case class and utilize case class object without using the REST interface.

```
case class Sample(
                  projectName : String,
                  modelName: String,
                  field2 : String,
                  field3: FieldConf,
                  field4: String,
                  field5: String,
                  field6 : Seq[field7]
                )
//FieldConf is another case class
```

how do I map my JSON string to this case class ?

Comment: You can write a simple formatter that maps the JSON to the case class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configured your akka-http to unmarshal JSON to your case class, you had to configure some JSON library as the marshaller.

You can use the same library directly to parse and decode your case class.

For example, here's how you would do it using Circe:

```
import io.circe.parser.decode

decode[MyCaseClass]("{...}")
```